# How to make icons like iCloud?

Tags: html, css, icloud

Does anybody know how to make this really easy? I'm a starter and would like to have 3 icons on my website to make a icloud-based website for a task on school.
I just don't really know how to do it, I already did some research but I didn't find anything. Inspect element is a bit to hard to understand yet... Any help is welcome!

[iCloud Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCizE.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. There may be another [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) site where this type of graphics question is on topic but read their help center first.

Comment: This site is for computer programming, not graphic design. How does your Question relate?

Comment: You should probably also check if those icons are public domain. Ripping off IP (especially Apple's) can have very negative consequences.

Comment: @Ethilium I don't want to fake anything I just want the same shape.

Comment: Sorry didn't know this... Thanks for informing me. @BSMP

Comment: @LucasVerhoest, you should have stated so in your question. The way it currently is written, it sounds like you want those exact icons, shape and image.

Comment: @Ethilium sorry will try to explain it better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a start for your homework :)

```css
body {
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari     5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1     to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

div.one,
div.two,
div.three {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Some text</div>
<div class="two">Some text</div>
<div class="three">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy! :) Appreciate it

Comment: then vote positive on the post :) glad I could help!

Comment: I can't since I don't have 15 score but i'll when i'm there ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.icloud-icon-container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
}

.icloud-icon {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

.icloud-icon-label {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 icloud-icon-container">
      <div class="icloud-icon"></div>
      <p class="icloud-icon-label">Icon Title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

[image: iCloud icon]

Find more at https://www.google.com/search?q=icloud+icon

### Also the [Assembly app](https://appsto.re/us/Ixdd9.i) is my favorite graphics app.

You could use it for making high-res icons by dragging and dropping shapes. It makes 4096x4096 graphics. It is also free but now there is a paid subscription  for more features. Since I had the app before the subscription was made, they gave it to me for free.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: You welcome! I have told many people and lot changed their lives completely.